# SP renewal and update keyvault through terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault, azure-service-principal

I want to update the details of an expired SP through terraform. I can regenerate the SP by changing the expiration date for the SP. but the SP details are been stored in the keyvault. So while updating the keyvault with the same id/secret it errors out. Is there a way to update/delete  the key_vault secret through terraform ?

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sp_arm_client_id" 
{ 
name = "ARM-CLIENT-ID" 
value = az_sp.app_id key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.storable_kvs[each.key].id 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your scenario in my environment and I was successfully able to do the changes and it got stored in current version and the previous one was in older version using the below code:

```
provider "azuread" {}

provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}
data "azuread_application" "appreg" {
  display_name="ansumanterraformtest"
}
resource "azuread_application_password" "apppass" {
  application_object_id = data.azuread_application.appreg.object_id
  end_date_relative = "3h"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name = "kvname"
  resource_group_name = "ansumantest"
}
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "demo_sp_client_id" {
  name         = "demo-sp-client-id"
  value        = data.azuread_application.appreg.application_id
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "demo_sp_client_secret" {
  name         = "demo-sp-client-secret"
  value        =azuread_application_password.apppass.value
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:** You might be getting the error if that secret in keyvault was not created from terraform . If it was created from portal or any other source then you have to first import that secret to terraform state and then change it so that the terraform can manage it .

**Import command:**

```
terraform import azurerm_key_vault_secret.example "https://example-keyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/example/fdf067c93bbb4b22bff4d8b7a9a56217"
```

**Reference:**

[azurerm_key_vault_secret | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_secret)

Comment: I'll check this by next week and will update the detail. Thanks

Comment: Hello @VenkateshRamanujam, any update?

Comment: Thanks, for checking the scenario and for a detailed explanation, it works, sorry for the delayed response.